# Back button causes dropdown to have different values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-9, html-select

I have an ASP.Net MVC app, and when a user clicks a certain link, I do the following:

```
var orderID = returnStatus["Data"];
var url = '@Url.Content("~/OrderEntry/OrderDetail")?orderID=' + orderID;
window.location.href = url;
```

This works great, however, when I click the back button, my html dropdown changes from:

```
Zone: <select id="Zones" name="Zones" style="width: 150px"><option value="1">Zone 1</option>
<option value="2">Zone 2</option>
<option value="3">Zone 3</option>
<option value="4">Zone 4</option>
</select>
```

to this:

```
Zone: <select id="Zones" name="Zones" style="width: 150px"><option value="QUOTE">Quote</option>
<option value="SUBM">Submitted</option>
<option value="INPRD">In Production</option>
<option value="CANC">Cancelled</option>
<option value="COM">Complete</option>
<option value="CH">Credit Hold</option>
</select>
```

These statuses are defined in a dropdown later in the code, and I'm not sure why they have moved up to this dropdown?

Both of these dropdowns are populated from the model.  It's almost as if the model is trying to re-generate this html, but the values are somehow incorrect?

Here is the Razor syntax:

```
Zone: @Html.DropDownList("Zones", Model.Zones, new { style = "width: 150px" } )
```

This doesn't appear to happen in Firefox or Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it had to do with the fact that my ID was called "Zones".  I changed this ID to AcctManagerZones and everything is working fine now.

Edited: It appears this wasn't exactly the answer either.  It apparently has to do with the way IE caches the page.  I still got the same thing, until I turned page caching off, then it worked.